# Combination of Jquery ,bootstrap and Carousel JS written breaks after Locker Service Upgrade

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

For a lightning community ,I have a small component built ,that worked well before locker .

The code uses bootstrap ,jquery 2.2.0 and ltng:require tags

Here is the component code

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="HomePageCmpController">
<ltng:require scripts="/resource/LightningComponentStyles/js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js,
                       /resource/LightningComponentStyles/js/bootstrap.min.js,
                       /resource/LightningComponentStyles/js/carousel.js"


              afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}"/>
  <aura:attribute name="lstcarouselContents" type="HomePageCmpController.Carousel[]"/>
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.getCarouselFeed}" />

 </aura:component>
```

The Carousel.js has a self invoking function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#Carousel").carousel({
    interval: 7e3
})
});
var clickEvent = !1;
$("#Carousel").on("click", ".-carousel-menu a", function() {
clickEvent = !0, $(".-carousel-menu li").removeClass("active"),    $(this).parent().addClass("active")
 }).on("slid.bs.carousel", function(e) {
   if (!clickEvent) {
       var a = $(".a-carousel-menu").children().length - 1,
        s = $(".a-carousel-menu li.active");
       s.removeClass("active").next().addClass("active");
       var c = parseInt(s.data("slide-to"));
       a == c && $(".a-carousel-menu li").first().addClass("active")
   }
   clickEvent = !1
});
```

I have also raised a case with **case No - 13966262** so any help appreciated on this

Comment: I also have problems with using bootstrap.js - e.g. tooltip() function is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like with new Winter 17 updates to the locker service ,this works now .So the updates to locker have seemed to fix this .